# jQuery - Adding classes from child elements to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to add the different classes from each separate anchor to their parent `<li>` tags. The general HTML code looks like this:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <div>Title Text</div>
    <span class="tag"><a href="#" class="Class1">Class1 Link</a>, <a href="#" class="Class2">Class2 Link</a>, <a href="#" class="Class3">Class3 Link</a></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Title Text</div>
    <span class="tag"><a href="#" class="Class4">Class4 Link</a>, <a href="#" class="Class5">Class5 Link</a>, <a href="#" class="Class6">Class6 Link</a></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The closest jQuery scripting I have works to an extent, but it is merely grabbing the first anchor class it encounters and adds it to every `<li>` tag in the unordered list.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('span.tag a').each(function(){
        var tagClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $('span.tag a').closest('li').addClass(tagClass);
});
```

Any help in getting this to work properly would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` instead of the `$('span.tag a')`, the latter select all the `a` elements and subsequently all the parent `li` elements. You can also use the `.addClass()` callback function:

```
$('ul.list > li').addClass(function() {
    return $('span.tag a[class]', this).map(function() {
        return this.className;
    }).get().join(' ');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UXSa7/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `this` reference to find the correct parent for that instance, rather than selecting them all again, which causes jQuery to take the first `a` tags parent `li`, then takes the class name of that element.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('span.tag a').each(function(){
        var tagClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $(this).closest('li').addClass(tagClass);
    });
});
```

You can also use `$(function(){` instead of `$(window).load(function () {` to make this run as soon as the DOM is ready, rather then when all assets are loaded.